# How to read global-set-key in .emacs file

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace, it has this setting to

```
(global-set-key "\C-c_w" 'whitespace-mode)
(global-set-key "\C-c_t" 'whitespace-toggle-options)
(global-set-key "\C-c=w" 'global-whitespace-mode)
(global-set-key "\C-c=t" 'global-whitespace-toggle-options)
```

What exactly do i need to type to use these key sequence? Ctrl-c and _ and w?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to type `C-c _ w`, `C-c _ t`, 
`C-c = w`, and  `C-c = t`.

Of course, those bindings will work only if `C-c _` and `C-c =` are prefix keys.  (See the Elisp manual, node `Prefix Keys`.)